# Instantiation of User Controls dissapearing on InitalizeComponent() when modifiyng Form

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022

Hi everyone and thank you in advance.
I have created a User Control named PanelOption that is a panel with a CheckBox and a TextBox, and these are inside a FlowPanelLayOut.
It runs well and everything works perfectly.

The problem comes when I modify the form where these PanelOption are. They dissapear from the InitializeComponent method as I show you below:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(CrearMultipleForm));
        this.txtEnunciado = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txtPuntaje = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblPuntaje = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lbNumPreg = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.FlowPanelOpciones = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.panelOptionSM1 = new Custom_Components.PanelOption('A');
        this.panelOptionSM2 = new Custom_Components.PanelOption('C');
        this.panelOptionSM3 = new Custom_Components.PanelOption('B');
        this.panelOptionSM4 = new Custom_Components.PanelOption('D');
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.botonMinus = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.botonPlus = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnCrear = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnCancelar = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnRespAbierta = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnVF = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnMultiple = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.FlowPanelOpciones.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
```

Here you can see the objects panelOptionSM1, panelOptionSM2... being instantiated . But as I said when I modify the form on the designer, Visual Studio removes the instantiation of the objects like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(CrearMultipleForm));
        this.txtEnunciado = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txtPuntaje = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblPuntaje = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lbNumPreg = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.FlowPanelOpciones = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.botonMinus = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.botonPlus = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnCrear = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnCancelar = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnRespAbierta = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnVF = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.btnMultiple = new QuizifyIU.Controles_Personalizados.Boton();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.FlowPanelOpciones.SuspendLayout();
        this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
```

The funny part is that the rest of the code concerning these objects remains untouched regardless of modifying the form. The rest of the code I am refereing:

```
// panelOpcionSM1
        // 
        this.panelOptionSM1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.panelOptionSM1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.panelOptionSM1.Name = "panelOpcionSM1";
        this.panelOptionSM1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 48);
        this.panelOptionSM1.TabIndex = 110;
        // 
        // panelOpcionSM4
        // 
        this.panelOptionSM4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.panelOptionSM4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 57);
        this.panelOptionSM4.Name = "panelOpcionSM4";
        this.panelOptionSM4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 48);
        this.panelOptionSM4.TabIndex = 112;
        // 
        // panelOpcionSM2
        // 
        this.panelOptionSM2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.panelOptionSM2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 111);
        this.panelOptionSM2.Name = "panelOpcionSM2";
        this.panelOptionSM2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 48);
        this.panelOptionSM2.TabIndex = 111;
        // 
        // panelOpcionSM3
        // 
        this.panelOptionSM3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.panelOptionSM3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 165);
        this.panelOptionSM3.Name = "panelOpcionSM3";
        this.panelOptionSM3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(525, 48);
        this.panelOptionSM3.TabIndex = 109;
```

And also:

```
private Custom_Components.PanelOption panelOptionSM3;
    private Custom_Components.PanelOption panelOptionSM1;
    private Custom_Components.PanelOption panelOptionSM4;
    private Custom_Components.PanelOption panelOptionSM2;
```

This only happens when I modify the form, not when I rebuild the solution or change the code of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add those lines manually to `InitializeComponent`? It seems you initialize `PanelOption` with a parameterized constructor. If it has no default constructor, then without implementing a custom `CodeDomSerializer` the designer will not have a clue how to regenerate the initialization code for such a component when you modify the form.

The simplest solution is to add a public default constructor to `PanelOption` and turn the original constructor parameter to a public property. Alternatively, you can add those panels to the form manually, outside of the `InitializeComponent` method (in which case they will not appear in the designer).